# Google sign in fails in android 5.0(Lollipop)or above Marshmallow but no in kitkat handleSignInResult:false

Tags: android, google-signin

Google sign in fails in android `5.0 (Lollipop)` or above `Marshmallow` but `no on kitkat`, on kitkat work normally.. I have try to some device and emulator but always can't login

the app just show the message from `snackbar` because `handleSignInResult:false`

how i can fix that?

this my code

```
package com.emergency.e_place;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.emergency.e_place.Util.SessionManager;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    SignInButton signInButton;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
    SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        setSession();
        setGoogleSignInAccount();
        declareWidget();
        setClickWidget();
    }

    private void setSession() {
        session = new SessionManager(LoginActivity.this);
    }


    private void setButtonGooglesignIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d("Hasil", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        Log.d("Hasil", "handleSignInResult:" + result.toString());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String nama = acct.getDisplayName();
            String email = acct.getEmail();
            String id = acct.getId();
            String foto = String.valueOf(acct.getPhotoUrl());

            session.createLoginSession(id,nama,email,foto);


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0), "GAGAL LOGIN", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void setGoogleSignInAccount() {
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }



    private void setClickWidget() {
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setButtonGooglesignIn();
            }
        });
    }

    private void declareWidget() {
        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signin_login_signin);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),connectionResult.getErrorMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you requesting runtime permission in marshmallow or up devices.

Comment: no just i can't login on android Lollipop or above

Comment: Do a thorough search before posting questions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because I not register OAuth 2.0 client IDs

go to [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) > **choose your project** > **menu credentials**

and then

1. click **create credentials**
2. **OAuth client ID**
3. in application type **choose android**
4. input name
5. input your SSA-1 usig `keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v`
6. input your package name
7. Click **create**
8. Download the **JSON**
9. copy file you just downloaded to folder app in your project
10. and make sure your setGoogleSignInAccount have code like this

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```